# I have the yaw rate, rear wheel speeds, and the radius of tires, how to find x and y speeds?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, kinematics

I only have these 3 data sets:

- rear right and left wheel speeds (they change with time)
- yaw rate (also changes with time)
- constant dynamic rolling radius

How am I supposed to find the directional speeds of the vehicle? I know that yaw rate is equal to (the difference between the rear right and left wheel speeds)/(the distance between the rear wheels)

and

therefore the distance between the rear wheels should be equal to (the difference between the rear right and left wheel speeds)/(yaw rate) right? But when I work with the data sets and do this calculation, I see that the distance is not constant when it should be!

And also, how to find the directional speeds with these given parameters only???

Comment: This was asked recently or a **very** similar question, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You're making the assumption, that all wheels are rolling without slip. Is it a front wheel driven vehicle? Slip could cause the deviations you see.

So, what directional speed are you looking for? Forward velocity? At the mid plane? Use the average of the two longitudinal speeds of the wheels (wheel rate/radius).

Lateral? Should be zero of you have no slip. If you have slip, you need to know how much, else you can't do much.

Sorry, I have no credits to make this a comment.